# How to convert a gauge in seconds into a ISO8601 date with promQL

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a `/metrics` HTTP route consumed by Prometheus.

It provides the following gauge:

```
# HELP process_start_time_seconds Start time of the process since unix epoch in seconds.
# TYPE process_start_time_seconds gauge
process_start_time_seconds 1658919747
```

Using the Prometheus Web UI, I'm able to write simple promQL expressions, for instance to grab the year of this timestamp:

```
year(process_start_time_seconds)
```

which returns `2022` as intended in the table below the query input.

Unfortunately there does not seem to be any function like `isodate(process_start_time_seconds)` that would return a string like `2022-07-27T11:02:27.000Z`

Is there an alternative way to obtain this human-friendly date value starting from a timestamp?

Comment: I think it's a reasonable request but I think you can't do this using PromQL. Please explain what you're trying to do as there may be a solution for that need. If you want to see "humanized" dates on Prometheus' Graph page, I think you're unable to do this. If you want dates in alert messages or console pages, see [Template reference](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/template_reference/) and e.g. `humanizeTimestamp` (I don't know what format this is).

Answer (score 5):

Grafana expects Unix timestamps in milliseconds, not seconds.
So you need to multiply your value by 1000 and select any of the date/time unit formats.

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/9595
[https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/sysadmin/GrafanaUnixEpochTime](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/sysadmin/GrafanaUnixEpochTime)